# Problem with imaginary/real parts of a complex function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have a problem with this code:

```
b = 2*23.5;
nu = 0.3;
Ee = 10^5;
h = 4.5;
z = x + y*I;
G = Ee/(2*(1 + nu));
Zline = (Ee*2*h)/(2*Pi*(1 - nu^2))*ArcSinh[Sqrt[z/b]];
Z = (Ee*2*h)/(2*Pi*(1 - nu^2))*1/Sqrt[z (z + b)];
u = ((1 - 2 nu)*Re[Zline] - y*Im[Z])/(2 G);
v = (2*(1 - nu)*Im[Zline] - y*Re[Z])/(2 G);
Final = D[v, x] - D[u, y]
Plot3D[Final, {x, -b, -b/10}, {y, b/10, b}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
Plot3D[u, {x, -b, 0}, {y, 0, b}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
Plot3D[v, {x, -b, 0}, {y, 0, b}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Functions `u` and `v` should be real-valued functions. Can I get their analytical form? I tried to use `ComplexExpand`, but still has something like `Arg[(x + I y) (47. + x + I y)]`.

Then I calculate derivative with `Final = D[v, x] - D[u, y]`. I don't understand why this line doesn't work:

```
Plot3D[Final, {x, -b, -b/10}, {y, b/10, b}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Comment: The problem with `Final` is that you are taking derivatives of expressions that have `Re` and `Im` as `Head`s. *Mathematica* doesn't like taking derivatives of those functions: look at the output of `D[Re[f[x]],x]`. The same thing happens with `Conjugate`, so doing the obvious thing of replacing `Re[a]` with `(a + Conjugate[a])/2` won't work.

Comment: I suspect you need to use numerical derivatives. Have a look at `ND` ( which requires the `NumericalCalculus` package: do `Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]`

Comment: Have you tried an explicit `TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}` setting in `ComplexExpand[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = 2*23.5;
nu = 0.3;
Ee = 10^5;
h = 4.5;
z = x + y*I;
G = Ee/(2*(1 + nu));
Zline = (Ee*2*h)/(2*Pi*(1 - nu^2))*ArcSinh[Sqrt[z/b]];
Z = (Ee*2*h)/(2*Pi*(1 - nu^2))*1/Sqrt[z (z + b)];
u = ComplexExpand[((1 - 2 nu)*Re[Zline] - y*Im[Z])/(2 G), 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}];
v = ComplexExpand[(2*(1 - nu)*Im[Zline] - y*Re[Z])/(2 G), 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}];
Final = D[v, x] - D[u, y];



   Plot3D[Final, {x, -b, -b/10}, {y, b/10, b}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 18, AxesStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: Knew it'd work…

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I need understand why there are points of discontinuity... They definitely should not be here